# Avoid select query retrieve fields in findByCriteria method of gvnix datatables

Tags: mysql, hibernate, datatables, gvnix, dandelion

I was monitoring the sql queries made by datables because some of my fields are type blob. I realize that even I modify my list.jspx with render="false" sortable="false" searchable="false" 
mysql query is selecting this field:

> Hibernate: select empleado0_.id as id1_0_, empleado0_.foto as
>   foto2_0_, empleado0_.fotocurp as fotocurp3_0_,
>   empleado0_.foto_miniatura as foto_min4_0_, empleado0_.nombre as
>   nombre5_0_, empleado0_.version as version6_0_ from empleado empleado0_
>   where lower(empleado0_.nombre) like ? escape '!' or
>   lower(empleado0_.fotocurp) like ? escape '!' limit ?

I was looking this method it looks like the point where the query execute in my Controller class:

```
datatablesUtilsBean_dtt.findByCriteria(Empleado.class, criterias, baseSearchValuesMap)
```

But I can't figure out how to avoid the query to select unnecessary heavy fields.

Comment: Did you annotated the blob field with @Lob? Which gvNIX version are you using?

Comment: @jmvivo  I'm working with gvnix.version: 1.5.1.RC4  and the field has @Lob annotacion:
`@Lob
private String foto;`